# Aws cloudformation join and sub together

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to generate list of ARNs using list of account ids. Below is the code ,

```
Principal:
         Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
         AWS:
             !Split
                - ','
                - !Sub
                    - 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::${acc_id}:root'
                    - acc_id: !Join
                        - !Sub ':root,arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::'
                        - !Ref AccountIds
```

But getting an error `"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined."`

I'm not understanding what's wrong in above code. Can someone help ?

Comment: Hey! Where does `AccountIds` come from? Is it defined as a CFN parameter? If so, is the data type a commaseparatedlist or a string? If it's a string that might be your issue, since the second parameter of !Join needs to be a list.

Comment: AccountIds is a list data type.